# Frequency control in Java

Tags: java, audio

Is there any class in java through which I can control audio frequencies.I have been through javadoc and found class `CompoundControl` but its vague.From where shall I start?

How can I achieve various frequencies of an audio file and then alter its dB levels, like an equalizer. I have been through the `CompoundControl` class which states:

> A CompoundControl, such as a graphic equalizer, provides control over two or more related properties, each of which is itself represented as a Control.

But I don't find any constants or methods.

Comment: I think a good starting point would be to tell us what it is exactly that you're trying to do.

Comment: It's not part of javax.sound.sampled. You will have to search for something written by someone else, or learn how to program digital signal processing algorithms. Or, if you have a "mixer" line that has this built in, then that is a possibility.

Answer (score 1):

You will find an equalizer implementation in [jlGui](http://www.javazoom.net/jlgui/jlgui.html), a Java open source Winamp clone. But keep in mind that the equalizer function only works with MP3 data.